# When I try to connect to google spreadsheet I got error -> 404 "you need permission"

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get in a Google spreadsheet via the [PHP API Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), but I am getting a 404->You need permission. The file has been given edit permissions to my user, which is the user I used to set up the JSON credentials via the Google Developers Console. What am I missing?

Here is my code :

```
     $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setApplicationName('BreezingForms Google Drive Spreadsheets');
        $this->client->addScope(array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'));

        // testing:
        // 197794184197-bt2q9knrdu1i54vgladd97ob196k4c6s.apps.googleusercontent.com
        // dImciIWj3WNOrIcYRbu9MFeA

        if (isset($_POST['gdata_custom_client_id']) && trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_id']) != '' && trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_secret']) != '') {

            $this->client->setClientId(trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_id']));
            $this->client->setClientSecret(trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_secret']));

            $db->setQuery("Update #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Set custom_client_id = " . $db->quote(trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_id'])) . ", custom_client_secret = " . $db->quote(trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_secret'])) . " Where form_id = " . intval($_REQUEST['form']));
            $db->execute();

        } else {

            $form_id = -1;

            if(JRequest::getInt('ff_form',-1) > 0){

                $form_id = JRequest::getInt('ff_form',-1);

            }else if(isset($_REQUEST['form'])){

                $form_id = intval($_REQUEST['form']);
            }

            $db->setQuery("Select * From #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Where form_id = " . $db->quote($form_id));
            $client = $db->loadObject();

            if ($client) {

                $this->client->setClientId($client->custom_client_id);
                $this->client->setClientSecret($client->custom_client_secret);
            }
        }

        $this->client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
        $this->client->setPrompt('consent');
        $this->client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
        $this->client->setAccessType('offline');


    }
    
    function onPropertiesDisplay($form_id, $tabs){
        
        if(!$form_id) return '';
        
        $error = '';
        
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        
        $db->setQuery("Select `title`,`name`,`id` From #__facileforms_elements Where form = " . intval($form_id) . " And `title` Not In ('bfFakeTitle','bfFakeTitle2','bfFakeTitle3','bfFakeTitle4','bfFakeTitle5') And `type` Not In ('','UNKNOWN') Order By ordering");
        $breezingforms_fields = $db->loadObjectList();
        
        $db->setQuery("Select `enabled`, `username`, `password`, `worksheet_id`, `spreadsheet_id`, `fields`, `meta`, `debug` From #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Where form_id = " . intval($form_id));
        $gdata = $db->loadObject();
        
        if( $gdata === null ){
            $gdata = new stdClass();
            $gdata->username = '';
            $gdata->password = '';
            $gdata->enabled = 0;
            $gdata->worksheet_id = '';
            $gdata->spreadsheet_id = '';
            $gdata->fields = '';
            $gdata->meta = '';
            $gdata->debug = 0;
        }
        
        $gdata->fields = explode('/,/', $gdata->fields);
        $gdata->meta   = explode('/,/', $gdata->meta);
        
        $gdata_spreadsheets = array();
        $gdata_worksheets = array();
        $gdata_columns = array();
        
        //if( $gdata->enabled == 1 ){
           
            
            try{
            
                $spreadsheetFeed = null;
                
                $auth_url = '';
                
                $db->setQuery("Select password From #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Where form_id = " . intval($form_id));
             $accessToken = $db->loadResult();
              // $accessToken='{"access_token":"ya29.a0ARrdaM--_ZKuuOfK3CyRsAubHXYgGlwMhLfg9x10fLbYhOq0Polqela1GjGYjhBO9Fi0v7LKuDauV4qA-uFLCilun0_NuQDuEFHjYb9iX0rcOjS6YWMDTHfe2UsyxJkyvlULrMIV7sh4_-_-vORj0kh6sw7o","expires_in":3599,"refresh_token":"1\/\/09aQ4SG_STBzBCgYIARAAGAkSNwF-L9Ir9FDHRmbwiLoCXglVSksa1tfyes6AdQedbTx2dqZKGh-ZTMT-M2i665x18NzT1luWu1Q","scope":"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/spreadsheets","token_type":"Bearer","created":1635842294}';

                if(!$accessToken){
                    
                    $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
                    
                    
                } else {
                    
                    try{
                        
                        $this->client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                        $token = json_decode($accessToken);
                
                        if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                            $this->client->refreshToken($token->refresh_token);
                            $tok = json_encode($this->client->getAccessToken());
                            $token = json_decode($tok);
                            $db->setQuery("Update #__breezingforms_addons_gdata set password = " . $db->quote($tok) . " Where form_id = " . intval($form_id));
                            $db->execute();
                        }
                        
                        $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($token->access_token, $token->token_type);
                        ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

                        $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
                        $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
                        
                    }catch(Exception $ee){
                        
                      //$accessToken = null;
                        //$auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
              $error=$ee->getMessage();
                                  
                                  }
                }

                if($spreadsheetFeed !== null){
                    foreach($spreadsheetFeed As $sheet){
                        $gdata_spreadsheets[$sheet->getId()] = $sheet->getTitle();
                    }
                }
                
                if($gdata->spreadsheet_id != '' && isset( $gdata_spreadsheets[$gdata->spreadsheet_id] ) && $spreadsheetFeed !== null){

                    $spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle($gdata_spreadsheets[$gdata->spreadsheet_id]);
                    $worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
                    
                    foreach ( $worksheetFeed as $sheet ){
                        $gdata_worksheets[$sheet->getId()] = $sheet->getTitle();
                    }
                    
                    if($gdata->worksheet_id != '' && isset( $gdata_worksheets[$gdata->worksheet_id] )){
                        
                        $worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle($gdata_worksheets[$gdata->worksheet_id]);
                        $cellFeed = $worksheet->getCellFeed();

                        foreach($cellFeed->getEntries() as $cellEntry) {
                            
                            $row = $cellEntry->getRow();
                            $col = $cellEntry->getColumn();
                            
                            if( $row > 1 ){
                                break;
                            }
                            
                            $gdata_columns[] = $cellFeed->getCell($row, $col)->getContent();
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            
            } catch(Exception $e){
                
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            }
        //}
        
        ob_start();
        $version = new JVersion();
        if(version_compare($version->getShortVersion(), '1.6', '<')){
            require_once JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . 'breezingforms_addons' . DS . 'breezingforms_addons_gdata_tmpl' . DS . 'properties.php';

        }else{
            require_once JPATH_SITE . DS . 'plugins' . DS . 'breezingforms_addons' . DS . 'gdata' . DS . 'breezingforms_addons_gdata_tmpl' . DS . 'properties.php';
        }
        $c = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $c;
    }
    
    function onPropertiesSave($form_id){
        
        if(!$form_id) return '';
        
        $accessToken = '';
        
        $reset_accessToken = false;
        
        if(isset($_POST['gdata_code']) && $_POST['gdata_code'] != ''){
            
            $accessToken =json_encode($this->client->authenticate($_POST['gdata_code']));
            
            
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['gdata_reset'])){
            $reset_accessToken = true;
            $accessToken = '';
            
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['gdata_fields']) && is_array($_POST['gdata_fields'])){
            $_POST['gdata_fields'] = implode('/,/', $_POST['gdata_fields']);
        }else{
            $_POST['gdata_fields'] = '';
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['gdata_meta']) && is_array($_POST['gdata_meta'])){
            $_POST['gdata_meta'] = implode('/,/', $_POST['gdata_meta']);
        }else{
            $_POST['gdata_meta'] = '';
        }
        
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        
        $db->setQuery("Select form_id From #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Where form_id = " . intval($form_id));
        $exists = $db->loadResult();
        
        if(!$exists){
            $db->setQuery("Insert Into #__breezingforms_addons_gdata (
                `form_id`, `enabled`,`password`,`spreadsheet_id`,`worksheet_id`,`fields`,`meta`) Values 
                (   ".intval($form_id).",
                    ".JRequest::getInt('gdata_enabled', 0).",
                    ".($accessToken ? $db->quote($accessToken).',' : '"",')."
                    ".$db->quote(hexToStr(JRequest::getVar('gdata_spreadsheet_id', "''"))).",
                    ".$db->quote(hexToStr(JRequest::getVar('gdata_worksheet_id', "''"))).",
                    ".$db->quote($_POST['gdata_fields']).",
                    ".$db->quote($_POST['gdata_meta'])."
                )");
            $db->query();
        } 
    else {
//$token1=json_encode(array("username" => "text",
   //"password" => "text"));
            $gspid = $reset_accessToken ? "''" : hexToStr(JRequest::getVar('gdata_spreadsheet_id', "''"));
            $wid = $reset_accessToken ? "''" : hexToStr(JRequest::getVar('gdata_worksheet_id', "''"));

            $db->setQuery("Update #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Set
                `enabled`  = ".JRequest::getInt('gdata_enabled', 0).",
                 ".($accessToken || $reset_accessToken ? "`password` = " . $db->quote($accessToken).',' : '')."
                `spreadsheet_id` = ".$db->quote(trim($gspid) == '' ? "''" : $gspid).",
                `worksheet_id` = ".$db->quote(trim($wid) == '' ? "''" : $wid).",
                `fields` = ".$db->quote($_POST['gdata_fields']).",
                `meta` = ".$db->quote($_POST['gdata_meta'])."
                ".($reset_accessToken ? ",`custom_client_id` = " . $db->quote("34263101371-4rcre0p6r9ehuhoat1d6ls8u84etuanp.apps.googleusercontent.com").', `custom_client_secret` = ' . $db->quote("IDq59sdLo6wC81KCUweDKVf2") : '')."
                 Where form_id = " . intval($form_id) . "
            ");
            $db->query();
        }
```

I give permission app to access on my Goole account, then I get auth token back from the Google account, but then I got "you to need permission"!?

Any idea?

Comment: I think you have a better chance of asking it to the API devs. This seems like a specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

**The error you are encountering comes from the fact that the `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` scope you are using is an invalid one.**

*The list of authorized scopes for Sheets API is the following one:*

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` which allows you to see, edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files;
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` which allows you to view and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app;
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`  which allows you to see and download all your Google Drive files;
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` which allows you to see, edit, create, and delete your spreadsheets in Google Drive;
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` which allows you to view your Google Spreadsheets.

Therefore, depending on the exact actions you want to allow your users to make, you will have to choose one of the scopes from the list above. Moreover, make  sure to delete the `token.json` file if you end up modifying the scopes.

#### Reference

- [Sheets API Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing).

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback!
OK, I will change scopes and try again, I will let you know the result! :)

Comment: Hi @ale13, I created an account on google developer and created a project and enabled API for the project but I didn't publish my app, I add test accounts, then create credentials for access, App type "Desktop app", and when I approved access to my Google account, again same, "you need permission" what I do wrong? tnx!

Comment: At which line are you getting the error? Moreover, can you share the entire error message?

Comment: Hi, it is all, I only get 404 "You need permission!" 
This line of code causes an error  `    $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();` if I comment it, the error disappears, it in normal because in that line want get spreadsheets , in some reason access to spreadsheets is refused, When I want to find spreadsheet based on ID, I found spreadsheet but same error. Hmm, very weird.

Comment: Hi @ale13, I found where is the problem, I use spreads API v3 which is turned off (what is causes 404 errors), I need make migrate on V4, do you know the best what how to do it?tnx